# How to delete everything before and after the ip address and port?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am wondering how to delete everything before and after the IP address and port in Notepad++. For example, from this:

```
email:pass | ip = 139.224.45.151 | port = 8080 | protocol = http | country = CN
email:pass | ip = 102.67.68.1 | port = 1080 | protocol = socks4 | country = ZZ
email:pass | ip = 94.54.211.197 | port = 80 | protocol = http | country = TR
email:pass | ip = 161.97.138.241 | port = 3128 | protocol = http | country = US
```

..to this

```
139.224.45.151:8080
102.67.68.1:1080
94.54.211.197:80
161.97.138.241:3128
```

Comment: Replace `^.*ip\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})\s*\|\s*port\s*=\s*(\d+).*$` with `\1:\2`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- find what: `^.* ip = *([\d\.]*).* port = *(\d*).*$`
- replace with: `$1:$2`
- `(o) regular expression` checked, `[_] , matches newline` unchecked